# How to hide .js files on wordpress website using php or wp plugins or any?

Tags: php, functions, jquery, javascript

How to hide my script files in wordpress. I tried this idea from this [blog](https://naveensnayak.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/including-external-javascript-and-css-files-in-php/)

```
// include a javascript file
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
   /* All your javascript code goes here */
</script>";
```

I got an error like this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ',' or ';' in  child-2\scripts.php on line 14
```

The 14th line is: `document.getElementById('next-btn').disabled = false;`

The `header.php` file has: `<?php include('scripts.php'); ?>`

How can I hide my javascript files?

Any plugins or any another method to hide my script.js files on wordpress website...

Comment: as it is right now this is a basic php question that got nothing to do with wordpress

Comment: Dear mark, I am asking for hiding js file on wordpress website using php or any another methods like special plugins or code etc......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not mix js and php. It seems (sure) that your js script (that was embed in the document), has php in it. That can work if the code is embed in the document as the php tags are open and close correctly.

If you link to a js file, there is no way for it to understand php tags, function...

If you want to add safely some php in a js file, one way is to echo the script in the document (but you don't want), other way is to [enqueue the script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) and use [wp_localize_script()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to handle some php var.

If you can show some more code about `script.php` ?